# Cannot install BIND dns with yum on Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.1

Tags: yum, dns, bind, oracle-database, oracle-linux

I am currently using Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.1 to use for Oracle RAC. However I am stuck at installing BIND (DNS Server) at the VM I've set up.

I've used the following command:

```
yum install bind_libs bind bind-utils
```

I get the error: `no package bind available`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would double check that these packages are in fact available on your system via whatever YUM repos you have configured first.

I know that for starters the package `bind_libs` is actually called `bind-libs`. You should get output similar to this with a `yum search "bind-"`.

#### Example

```
$ yum search "bind-"
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.anl.gov
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: centos.corenetworks.net
 * updates: bay.uchicago.edu
80 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
=================================================================================== N/S Matched: bind- ====================================================================================
bind-chroot.x86_64 : A chroot runtime environment for the ISC BIND DNS server, named(8)
bind-devel.i686 : Header files and libraries needed for BIND DNS development
bind-devel.x86_64 : Header files and libraries needed for BIND DNS development
bind-dyndb-ldap.x86_64 : LDAP back-end plug-in for BIND
bind-libs.x86_64 : Libraries used by the BIND DNS packages
bind-libs.i686 : Libraries used by the BIND DNS packages
bind-sdb.x86_64 : BIND server with database backends and DLZ support
bind-utils.x86_64 : Utilities for querying DNS name servers
```

#### Using an Oracle YUM repo?

If you go poking around you'll eventually stumble into Oracle's YUM repository. I found a packaged version of Bind there.

- [/repo/OracleLinux/OL6/latest/x86_64/](http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL6/latest/x86_64/)

You can read more about [setting up these repositories](http://public-yum.oracle.com/).

> The Oracle public yum server offers a free and convenient way to install the latest Oracle Linux packages as well as packages from the Oracle VM installation media via a yum client.
>
> You can download the full Oracle Linux and Oracle VM installation media via edelivery.oracle.com/linux. To stay current on errata updates, you may wish to subscribe to the Oracle Linux errata mailing list.
>
> This yum server is offered without support of any kind. If you require support, please consider purchasing Oracle Linux Support via the online store, or via your sales representative.

Comment: I have bind-libs.x86_64 and bind-utils.x86_64. I tried adding some repos, but to no success. Perhaps I'll use CentOS as the DNS server, and use oracle for RAC installation.

Comment: @TGO - see updates.

Comment: your answer was helpful, thanks for the help :]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed procedure for Oracle 12c RAC Installation using DNS.

http://www.dbacentral.com/2016/12/oracle-12c-rac-installation-on-linux-7.html